# what does it mean when kernel depth=1 in conv3d pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I would like to understand the difference between conv2d and conv3d in PyTorch.

What is the difference between:

```
conv3d(in, out, kernel_size(1,3,3))
```

and

```
conv2d(in,out,kernel_size(3,3))
```

I checked the official [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv3d.html) but I couldn't quite understand the difference between the two. Should conv3d in this case be the same as conv2d since the depth is 1? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to give an intuitive understanding of how a kernel works I would recommend to look how the cells(a.k.a Neurons) of a single feature layer are obtained.

For the 2D convolution you have the hight and width of the kernel layer(KL) that goes over a single feature layer(FL) from a 2D convolutional layers(CL). Because a CL can have numerous FLs, multiple KLs are then created in parallel and placed over the different FLs, so it can process them in parallel. This parallel processing is usually illustrated as a "stacked" structure of KLs, which is usually named just Kernel. Not only the singularity of the name "Kernel" from this plural structure can leads to confusion, but also the fact that the parallel processing of KLs are illustrated commonly as a stacking of KLs, creating an illusion of a depth dimension.
So important to remember: this is not a third dimension, this is just a parallel processing of KLs-FLs.

For a 3D convolution you need now 3D KL to process the 3D FL. This is now a true third dimension. The number of 3D KLs that will be "stacked", will be automatically adjusted so it can process parallel the multiple 3D FLs from your network.

**Regarding your question**:
Indeed, a 3D kernel with a depth 1 is the same as a 2D kernel, however the functions are builded differently for the different cases. That is, 2D for images with two dimensions (hight, width), and 3D for Images with three dimensions (hight, width, depth).

Answer (score 0):

They can yeild the same result in some particular cases.

Take `conv1d` and `conv2d` for example: with a (1, n) in the conv1d, you are going through a 1D input (i.e `w>0` and `h=1`) when the kernel has reached the end of the line its result is ready. On the con2d though, it is a 2D input you're working on (i.e. `w>0` and `h>0`), it will go to the next line, until it has reached the bottom line. So its result is also a 2D object.

Layers are added depth to the input/output you can have multiple `in` layers which will dictate the number of layers per kernel, and the `out` layer, the number of kernels.

If my observations are correct, we can say that a single-layered `d*h*w` tensor going through a `conv3d` (`1x3x3`) kernel is the same as a `d`-layered `h*w` tensor going through a `conv2d` with `d`, `d`-layered `3x3` kernels. The output shapes will be `(N, 1, d, h, w)` vs `(N, d, h, w)` (where `d` is used as the number of channels in the latter).

In some cases, you can get the same results (operations). However, when adding depth to your `conv3d` (layers could work as a 4th dimension), you won't be able to match that with a `conv2d`, as the name implies!

Answer (score 0):

In some sense, it is the same. They have separate implementations in the underlying cuDNN library, so there might be some performance differences (although is not always one would expect, cf. Pytorch forum [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nvidia-tensor-cores-not-being-used-for-nn-conv3d-3d-convolutions/90253/12) and [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/conv3d-vs-conv2d-speed/18132/5)).

But I would also say, it also makes the code better readable and prevents errors: you clearly see that it is a 2D convolution and you cannot make a mistake when defining the kernel shape.